# Is there a way to effectively use reactjs with WebSharper

Tags: f#, type-providers, websharper, funscript

I am currently exploring websharper. <strike>However, the UI.Next API seems kind of sluggish. Albeit, it is still experimental</strike>. I am thinking the speed and flexibility offered by Facebook's, reactjs and it's functional design, should make a great fit. Has any tried this? How successfully? Since UI.Next is merely a library to the WebSharper framework, one might expect an adapter to the reactjs library could similarly work...

Thank in advance for your response.

Comment: If you don't mind me asking, what in particular did you find sluggish about UI.Next?

Comment: @FyodorSoikin At the time, I was noticing a delay in the response from their UI.Next SinglePage template application. However, this delay appears to have gone away. Perhaps there were aspects of my machine that were causing it?

Answer (score 2):

Already does...

[Found the documentation clarifying this point](http://websharper.com/docs/ui.next)

> (WebSharper.UI.Next is...) A reactive DOM library for displaying these time-varying values in a functional way. If you are familiar with Facebook React, then you will find some similarities with this approach: instead of explicitly inserting, modifying and removing DOM nodes, you return a value that represents a DOM tree based on inputs. The main difference is that these inputs are nodes of the dataflow layer, rather than a single state value associated with the component.

Answer (score 1):

Although UI.Next has some 'react-like' features, it explicitly avoids the Virtual Dom approach which is the key underlying technology behind React.

The result is that in order to build a complex GUI in UI.Next you need to explicitly set up the necessary observables, rather than just rendering and handling events. Personally, I find this harder and more timeconsuming, but YMMV.

There are some tantalising indications that a binding to React may be on the cards quite soon:  http://websharper.com/blog-entry/4665/websharper-a-year-in-review mentions a forthcoming React library.